# Django error showing none type when it isn't none

Tags: python, geo

I am using a library called `PostCoder()` in order to work out the distance between two UK postcodes.

I am just getting started with this trying to test it out, unfortunately I can't get any further than the initial stage before I get the following error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Here is the code in my view:

```
origin_postcode = "W1 5PD"
dest_postcode = "LS3 2GG"

origin = str(pc.get('%s' % origin_postcode)['geo']['lat'])+','+str(pc.get('%s' % origin_postcode)['geo']['lng'])
dest = str(pc.get('%s' % dest_postcode)['geo']['lat'])+','+str(pc.get('%s' % dest_postcode)['geo']['lng'])
```

I don't understand how it can call this a `NoneType` when it has a hard coded value.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be here?

Comment: One of your `pc.get`s is probably `None` because the key you're trying to get isn't present. Show us the value of `pc`.

Comment: Also there is no use in `'%s' % origin_postcode`, just use `origin_postcode` by itself.

Comment: when I print pc this is the output: <postcodes.PostCoder object at 0x7f37fe530650> @AlexHall .

Answer (score 0):

Check out the return value of [`pc.get()`](https://postcodes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#postcodes.get). It returns `None` when the postal code is not available.

As far as I believe, the `postcodes` library is for UK's postal codes, and "W1 5PD" postal code is not a valid one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however I have been using different (valid) postcodes whilst testing... I just changed them for the sake of uploading the question

Comment: @smith_05_bird what is the result of `pc.get(valid_postalcode)`?

Comment: it is showing 'None' :/ --- I have tested this with lots of different postcodes that are definitly valid and it is still showing None

Comment: Ah, the library your using uses [UK-postcodes.com](http://www.uk-postcodes.com) to get the postal code information. The website [UK-postcodes.com](http://www.uk-postcodes.com) is currently down at this moment. I've just tried using it, check it out and if it works then ur code should work. It might work later.. Nonetheless, you should consider this case and catch the error when your coding.

Comment: Ahh i see! thanks, i'll try again later and let you know how that goes.